# Pointing domain to server-IP: Is Type A sufficient?

Tags: server

I want to point my domain to a certain server IP (at another provider).

I would like to ask if it is sufficient to change "Type A" and "Type A*" to the new server IP, or should "MX 10", "NS", etc. also be changed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: Yes, this is sufficient.